# How to disable automount of an harddrive?

Tags: hard-drive, automount, udev

I am working on a project, and for this I need to disable the aumounting of hard-drives in Ubuntu both at startup and when I plug an hard-drive.

I tried one solution with "edit-conf" disabling automount at org.gnome.desktop.media-handling but when I plug a hardrive ubuntu still mounts it an open a window even when I restart the computer in between.

There is also the fstab solution but the thing is I don't know in advance the UUID of the drive I don't want to mount automatically.

From want I understand there is the solution of editing an udev rule, but i'm not a specialist of that.

Answer (score 3):

Run these two commands:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount 'false'`
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount-open 'false'`

Or you can try it with a udev rule:
`sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/85-no-automount.rule`
Paste this line `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}="0"` and save the file.
Reboot the system.

Comment: It didn't work, I executed the two command then reboote, and when i plugged my hard-drive, ubuntu stills mount it.

Comment: You can try the udev rule I added above.

Comment: I didn't try the rule, but I have a question before, I plug the hard drives directly onto the SATA ports of my computer, How should I translate the rule? SUBSYSTEM=="sata"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add the module to the blacklist:

`sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

add:

> blacklist usb-storage

or

`echo "blacklist usb-storage" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Enabling it later should just be:

`sudo modprobe usb-storage`

Answer (score 0):

As Pabi wrote in his answer, run this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.media-handling automount 'false'
```

BUT: this will probably not be effective until the next reboot.

Lack of a reboot caused me to doubt the effectiveness of gsettings initially.  I found it when being very thorough in preparation for filing a bug, which I found I didn't need to do.  I've only tried this under sudo, however, so if you still have trouble, try doing it that way.  I want this effective system-wide and found this does the job.

You do not need to touch automount-open because it only applies when an automount happens, and you will have disabled that.